# Moving a circle along the X-axis

Tags: c, linux, opengl

I am making a circle move in x direction only. I have drawn the circle, but i am not able to move it in x direction. Am i missing anything?

```
void display()
{
    int count=0;                      //counter for checking purpose only

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawcircle(xxc,yyc,rr);           //draws a circle
    glFlush();
    xxc=xxc+deltax;                   //increment x coordinate only

    printf("%d",count);               //prints value of count

    if(xxc>100 || xxc<0 ) {           //to move between 100 and 0
        deltax=-deltax;               //for the to and fro motion of circle
    }
    count++;                          //increment count
    glutPostRedisplay();  

}
```

Comment: To start with, the expression `xxc>100 | xxc<0` doesn't do what you expect it to, since the single `|` is *bitwise or* and not logical or.

Comment: still it is not working.

Comment: Are you sure it's just not moving so fast that you can't see the movement? Instead of doing `glutPostRedisplay` in the `display` function, do it at larger intervals instead, say a few times per second? See e.g [`glutTimerFunc`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html) for how to set a timer in GLUT.

Comment: what if i try to rotate around a single point so that it traces a circular path.

Comment: Do that as an exercise.

Comment: In addition to glutTimerFunc, you might want to have a look at glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME). I'm guessing error can build up with glutTimerFunc and it's handy to know exactly how much time has elapsed. Taking the difference allows you do to things like xxc += deltax * elapsedTime, which will give a much smoother animation that will move at the same speed on different computers as well.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Although unusual, how does `if(xxc>100 || xxc<0 )` functioanl different from `if(xxc>100 | xxc<0 )` in _this_ usage?  Both perform `deltax=-deltax` when `xxc` is outside the 0 to 100 range and skip it when in range.

Comment: If you use logical or operator `||`, then if `xxc > 100` is true, then `xxc < 0` is not performed (due to [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)). With bitwise or `|` then both comparisons are performed no matter what, and the results are then combined with a bitwise or and then that result is used as the condition. In this simple case the end result is no different, but the way it arrives at that result is very much different.